# How do VPN providers acquire IP's?

Tags: vpn

Can someone explain how exactly VPN providers acquire the IP's they possess and in turn allocate to VPN's they posses?

Do they buy blocks of IP's and "own" them or do they "rent" ip blocks from some sort of distributor? Once a VPN provider acquires IP's do they simply set the IP they acquire as the gateway for all traffic it sends out?

Ive been trying to learn more about how VPN providers acquire IP's but many people are stating its not possible or not economically feasible - yet there are so many VPN providers and some being very small scale.

Lastly, how and where would an individual buy or rent IP's if I wanted to set up my own VPN's. Is there a minimum "block" amount id have to purchase? Who would I go to? What would the costs be?

Would appreciate some input.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 1 answer to this.

Established providers may join the appropriate [regional authority](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/rirs.html) (RIR; such as AFRINIC, ARIN, RIPE) to get IP addresses like regular ISPs do. But if you need IPv4, this would probably not be a good solution because RIRs themselves have mostly run out.

Many providers will simply get IP addresses from their ISP's, but there is also a market in buying and selling blocks of IPv4's, as well as some more dodgy unofficial ways of getting space.

The practical minimum number of IPv4 addresses you would purchase/rent if you want flexibility of upstream provider is 256 (a /24 block, which previously was "class C"), or multiple thereof. The practical IPv6 minimum is a /48.

If you want to do something small scale, you could use fewer addresses and make use of NAT and DNS - depending on your goals.    Also, going to places like AWS you can Rent IP space on an as needed basis - but are then bound to use AWS's network - no doubt other VPN providers do something similar.

Comment: The "class" referencing is old, not really used, and instead you would want to get a `/24` block.  Still 254 usable addreses....

Comment: @ivanivan: 256, because it does not have to correspond to a broadcast LAN. It can very well consist of point-to-point links (where each client has a PPP "pipe"), or be used entirely as a NAT pool (where topology is outright irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) controls the distribution of IP addresses for IPv4 and IPv6.

The available IP addresses are allocated to five Regional Internet Registries (RIRs) in blocks of `/8` in IPv4 (16,777,216 contiguous IPv4 addresses) and `/12` in IPv6. The RIRs then allocate the IP addresses to companies and agencies within their region.

Since ICANN and the RIR's are in charge of the allocation, the addresses are rented.

How VPN providers handle IP addressing will depend on the VPN service. Large scale providers may be working directly with the RIR's, but small scale providers are likely going through a local ISP.

In it's simplest form, a VPN is simply a secure connection between two computers over the Internet, so this would simply use the existing IP addresses of those computers. There are many other forms of VPN services that may have varying requirements for IP addresses.

[source](https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/ip-addresses-beginners-guide-04mar11-en.pdf)